# PHP's mail() function working in CLI but not in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, email, msmtp

I'm using **msmtp** as a relay and trying to send an email with the mail() function. It works perfectly in CLI, but does nothing in Apache. My PHP configs for cli and apache are identical, there are no errors in any of the logs and I'm really out of ideas.

Any idea what this could be caused by?

Comment: If you're using RHEL or CentOS SELinux might actively restrict and prevent apache from establishing outgoing mail/network connections.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I'm using debian. No SELinux there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the solution to this problem. I'm using **msmtp**, which is an SMTP proxy and works similar to sendmail, thus, when trying to send a mail, the msmtp command is called from php with similar syntax to sendmail.

Now, the msmtp command will be run by the same user apache2 is running under. In my case www-data.

There is a configuration file for msmtp (/etc/.msmtp_php in my case) that needs to be readable by the www-data user.

The reason CLI was working and Apache PHP was not is, that I was running the CLI under root, which had the correct permissions for the file, but apache2 is runnuing under www-data, which didn't have those permissions.

> **So the solution is:** *chown* the /etc/.msmtp_php file to
>   *www-data:www-data* and chmod the same file to *0600*, otherwise, msmtp will 
>   complain about loose permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much, almost lost one day, trying to figure out what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

One way you can send mail by using it in exec() function.

```
exec('usr/bin/mail <parameter>', $output); //$output for debugging
```

Check output for response, but still you have to resolve your settings for using php `mail()` function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: **Check whether you are actually using the `php.ini` file you believe.**

Apache can for example use different `php.ini` location for every user, if `mod_suphp` is enabled. With suPHP, the location is set with `suPHP_ConfigPath` directive in `mods-enabled/suphp.conf` and it defaults to PHP's compiled default path even when different `PHPIniDir` is set for global configuration. ([PHP: The configuration file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) gives more information about the order where `php.ini` gets searched.)

1. You can get the `php.ini` location by using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` within same directory.
2. You can directly get the current SMTP server used by `mail()` function with [`ini_get()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php):

   `<?php echo ini_get('SMTP') . ":" . ini_get('smtp_port'); ?>`

If the SMTP server is the one it should be, the `mail()` function should return `TRUE` if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery and otherwise `FALSE`. In both cases, if the function was able to connect the SMTP server, more information on the connection can be found in **SMTP server log file**.

If `mail()` returns `FALSE` without connecting to the SMTP, check whether you have **safe_mode on and `mail()` additional_parameters set**. From changelog (PHP version 4.2.3):

> The **additional_parameters** parameter is disabled in safe_mode and the
>   `mail()` function will expose a warning message and return `FALSE` when
>   used.

Comment: This answer needs improvement in regards to suggestions about mail() returning TRUE/FALSE. It needs an example.