# PHP mail() function working from command line but not working with apache

Tags: php, email, smtp, apache2, msmtp

My problem is that php script which has to send mail doesn't send it if I run it in browser, but works in cli. 
This doesn't help
[PHP's mail() function working in CLI but not in Apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/842221/phps-mail-function-working-in-cli-but-not-in-apache)

In both /etc/php/7.0/fpm and /etc/php/7.0/cli same mail settings:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25 
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtprc -t"
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/maillog
```

If I type in terminal

```
php -r mail("my_mail@gmail.com", "Test", "test");
```

it works, also it works if I type

```
sudo -u www-data php -r mail("my_mail@gmail.com", "Test", "test");
```

However, if I try to send mail from php interactive mode `php -a`
and then simply type there `mail("my_mail@gmail.com", "Test", "test");` I get `/etc/msmtprc permission denied`. I tried to `chmod 666 /etc/msmtprc` (however `ls -al` shows `-rw------- 1 www-data www-data 267 Apr  4 11:10 /etc/msmtprc`, so I think no need in allowing access) I get error like `msmtp: /etc/msmtprc: contains secrets and therefore must be owned by you`
 
file `msmtprc` is chmodded this way `chmod 600 msmtprc`, according to many tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I understood what is wrong simply attempting different configurations, so writing answer to my own question :)

in php7, there are apache2, fpm, cli, and mods-available folders in /etc/php/7.0/
Some of the tutorials/questions say that to make msmtp work you have to edit php.ini in fpm and cli folder. That's not fully true. To make apache2 working with msmtp so you could use mail() function to send emails in php scripts, you have to configure php.ini in /etc/php/7.0/apache2. The mail configuration of all 3 php.ini files should be the same, which is

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25 
sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/msmtp -C /etc/msmtprc -t"
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = /var/log/maillog
```

Note, that -C option shows the path to your msmtprc file, which should be the same as here. Also note that since you have installed and configured msmtp, so you can send mails from command line (not using php), you DON'T need to install sendmail on your server. Simply configure you php.ini files and everything will work